# FactorDB can't factorize number generated by getPrime

Tags: python, module, python-import, factorization

I tried to generate big prime number and minus one then trying to find divisors but it just gave the exact number.

```
from factordb.factordb import FactorDB
from Crypto.Util.number import getPrime

N = getPrime(500)-1
f = FactorDB(N)
f.connect()
result=f.get_factor_list()
print(result)
```

etc N= 2277647640912515176017915577262253148010022211563343265354397390598683113880432667265598641213983592578231532027799084013035762860730715053597514693432
result just gave [2277647640912515176017915577262253148010022211563343265354397390598683113880432667265598641213983592578231532027799084013035762860730715053597514693432]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's because the number is actually huge and FactorDB still didn't contain it.

[image: The factorization of the number]

Now that number is FF, fully factored, so you can get its factors, while when you posted this answer it was still C, *"composite without known factors"*.

- http://factordb.com/status.html

Consider reading this documentation page about FactorDB.